# Do annotations on a class still get called when only accessing static members?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I have the following class:

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

If I reference it in my main camel route, like so:

```
package com.example.integration;

import hello.*;

import org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;


public class TestCamelSpring {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("camelspring.xml");
            ProducerTemplate camelTemplate = context.getBean("camelTemplate", ProducerTemplate.class);

        Application.main(args);
        System.out.println("Message Sending started");
        camelTemplate.sendBody("jms:queue:testQSource","Sample Message");
        System.out.println("Message sent");

    }

}
```

Do my annotations in Application.class still get accessed even though I only reference Application.main?

I ask because the @EnableAutoConfiguration is supposed to configure the application for Tomcat, but now that I am not running Application.class directly, the application is defaulting to jetty and then I get an error that WebSockets are only supported in Tomcat.

Has anyone had this issue before or know how to solve it?

Here is the stack trace. I can see from the console log that it never starts the Tomcat instance that it does when the whole class is accessed in the example. It seems to be continuing as if it is a jetty app rather than Tomcat. Please correct me if any of these assumptions are wrong:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Websockets are currently only supported in Tomcat (found class org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory). 
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.websocket.WebSocketAutoConfiguration$1.customize(WebSocketAutoConfiguration.java:74)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:67)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:54)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1545)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
... 16 more
```

Comment: A more generic question could be *"Do annotations on a class still get called when only accessing static members?"*

Comment: You're probably right. I've changed the question to more properly reflect my problem. I appreciate your input.

Comment: Where does the exception happen? In `camelTemplate.sendBody(..)`? That bean is completely unrelated to the `ApplicationContext` created by `Application`.

Comment: I've added the stack trace. But to be specific, the error happens in Application.main(args) and specifically when it is doing the SpringApplication.run call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, annotations cannot be "called".

Annotations are data, not code. In your case Spring Boot reads your annotations when you call `SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);` and performs necessary configurations, therefore it doesn't matter how you call `Application.main()`.

I guess your problem is caused by the fact that you have Jetty in the classpath, and it forces Spring Boot to use Jetty rather than Tomcat as embedded servlet container.

So, try to do the following:

- Find out how Jetty appeared in your classpath
  Use `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` if you use Maven
- If you don't need Jetty in the classpath, exclude it from dependencies
- Otherwise, you need to force Spring Boot to ignore presence of Jetty
  Something like `exclude = EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.EmbeddedJetty.class` in `@EnableAutoConfiguration` may help